# Two "fixed-top" bootstrap 5 navbars at different sections of the page

Tags: alignment, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a landing page where there is one main navigation bar at the top of the page that is set to "fixed-top" so that the navbar follows as the user scrolls down. In my `[code-pen example](https://codepen.io/njmark88/pen/YzjxxXb?editors=1000)`, I have an additional navbar labeled "scrollbar" on top of the "Call To Action" section.

How can I achieve the following:

Once the main "navbar" reaches the position of the "scrollbar", how can I have the main "navbar" push down the "scrollbar" as the user continues to scroll down the page?

I need to set "fixed-top" of the "scrollbar" relative to the top of the "Call To Action" section, not the top of the landing page.

I attempted to set the "scrollbar" to "fixed-top" as well, unfortunately that just aligns it to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the following code in react :

```
const LandingPage = () => {
    const fixedScrollbarNav = () => {
        (window.pageYOffset > 928) ? document.querySelector(".scrollbar-nav").classList.add("fixed-scrollbar") : document.querySelector(".scrollbar-nav").classList.remove("fixed-scrollbar");
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => fixedScrollbarNav());
        return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", () => fixedScrollbarNav());
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
                <Navbar />
                <SearchBar />
                <Scrollbar />
                <Cta />
                <FeaturedCities />
                <Contact />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default LandingPage;
```

By adding an event-listener on scroll, I was able to call a function that adds or removes specific CSS classes that change the position of the scrollbar from relative to fixed and top: 27px

```
.scrollbar-nav {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 27px !important;
}

.fixed-scrollbar {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    z-index: 99 !important;
}
```